# How to overwrite file which is using by an application, with ftp commands

Tags: batch-file, ftp, overwrite

I need to distribute files over network to other servers *(OS: Windows Server 2003)* with below ftp script.*(See attachment-1)* I'm trying to overwrite some files which are currently used by an application. I should not stop the application while I doing this. When I try to use this script, I'm getting an error *(See attachment-2)* and the file did not overwrite.

**Attachment-1**
ftp_command.txt

```
username
password
lcd C:\deploy
bin
prompt
mput *.txt
disconnect
bye
```

runner_command.bat

```
ftp -s:/home/script/ftp_script.txt <IP Address>
```

**Attachment-2**
Error Message:
*550  The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no way around that with ftp.  The file is in use--if it were to be replaced, the application that's using it would likely fail because it would not be aware of the change.  You will have to find a way to stop the application that is using the file.

Comment: When I use **FileZilla**, I can overwrite the files which are in use. Weird :S FileZilla beat the IIS-Ftp this time :)